# increase the power rating of resistor so that higher current can flow through it

Tags: resistance

how to find a resistance value without using multimeter?
resistance power rating is 1/4W.
i tried giving 5volts and finding current but the resistor got heated and power supply was giving a beep sound.

Comment: no other element is to be added by the way

Comment: (1) Proper English capitalization is not optional on EE.SE .  (2) It's not clear what you are asking and why.

Comment: Often resistors have markings, such as color bands, to indicate the nominal resistance value. Google "resistor color code" for details.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to increase a resistors power rating is to heat sink it. Anything greater than 5 Volt 50 milli amps through a 1/4th watt resistor will need a heatsink.

The only practical solution is using a properly sized resistor. Or reducing the voltage dropped by said resistor.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the power rating submerse it in oil or water to keep it cool. you'll also need a stronger powersupply.

A better move is probably to use a lower voltage, or to use a fixed current powersupply and measure the voltage on the resistor.